# Completely Remove Module

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to do a mass export and found out that a module was causing an issue via system.log.

I removed the offending module via connect and double checked the usual places for any lingering files, but it looks to be removed. However, I am currently getting this error when running the export:

> 2015-12-31T02:20:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   include(Ameex/Adminlog/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory  in
>   /chroot/home/xx/xxx.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> 2015-12-31T02:20:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'Ameex/Adminlog/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/chroot/home/xx/xxx.com/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/rennraci/rennracing.com/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/xx/xxx.com/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/xx/xxx.com/html/lib:.:/opt/nexcess/php54u/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/nexcess/php54u/root/usr/share/php')
>   in /chroot/home/xx/xxx.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

**Ameex** would be the offending module. So it would appear that something is trying to access the module even though it's removed.

```
Line 94 of Autoload.php is :         return include $classFile;
```

Anyway to disconnect the bad module?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache, re-indexed, and re-compiled (if applicable)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could check :

- Did you remove the module declaration from app/etc/modules/ ?
- Did you clear the cache from the administration page ?
- Did you remove all the files in var/cache/ ?
- Can you research the term **ameex** in all the app/code files ? Maybe there is another module using it.